# ActionMailer Doubt in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

My Application has a lot of modules like profiles, places, comments etc. So Inorder to send a mail when something interesting happens like a new comment, a new place, do I need to create many mailer classes(ProfileMailer, PlaceMailer, CommentMailer) and also corresponding observer classes to implement mail?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest `acts_as_loggable` or similar plugin that tracks different events in your app (whenever anything new is created: place, profile, comment) and then create mailer for logged events.